# Bokeh and Matplotlib on the same Jupyter Notebook - Matplotlib not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh

I've bumped into a problem while running Jupyter Notebook with Bokeh and Matplotlib in the same notebook (Bokeh for interactivity, Matplotlib for specific plot types not supported by Bokeh).

Once I execute a cell which is going to run Bokeh, then Matplotlib will not show up anymore in the output cell. Let's consider the following example:

In the first cell:

```py
import yaml
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.themes import Theme
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.sampledata.sea_surface_temperature import sea_surface_temperature

output_notebook()

def bkapp(doc):
    df = sea_surface_temperature.copy()
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)

    plot = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', y_range=(0, 25),
                  y_axis_label='Temperature (Celsius)',
                  title="Sea Surface Temperature at 43.18, -70.43")
    plot.line('time', 'temperature', source=source)

    def callback(attr, old, new):
        if new == 0:
            data = df
        else:
            data = df.rolling('{0}D'.format(new)).mean()
        source.data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(data)

    slider = Slider(start=0, end=30, value=0, step=1, title="Smoothing by N Days")
    slider.on_change('value', callback)

    doc.add_root(column(slider, plot))

    doc.theme = Theme(json=yaml.load("""
        attrs:
            Figure:
                background_fill_color: "#DDDDDD"
                outline_line_color: white
                toolbar_location: above
                height: 500
                width: 800
            Grid:
                grid_line_dash: [6, 4]
                grid_line_color: white
    """, Loader=yaml.FullLoader))

show(bkapp)
```

In the second cell:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = y = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.cos(x**2 + y**2)
f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.contourf(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```

As you can see, Matplotlib plot will not show up. What can I try?

Comment: Hmm, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your both of the codes seem perfectly fine. you can try it [here](https://hub.gke2.mybinder.org/user/ipython-ipython-in-depth-sytgrsnd/notebooks/binder/Index.ipynb#)
It might work.

Comment: I get an error 404 when I click on your link. I think because of this your answer won't be accepted.

Comment: Thankyou for informing. I have edited it, now it might work.

Comment: The link is still not working. Maybe this functionlity is blocked.